# Use UIImagePickerController in qt application

Tags: objective-c, qt, uikit, uiimagepickercontroller

i am using qt 5.3 on mac to develop an iOS application. I want to use `UIImagePickerController` with objective-c to pick an image from ios gallery and show it in qt. I know how use objective-c code in qt. To use `UIImagePickerController`, i need to add `<UIKit/UIKit.h>` in objective-c file (.mm), but i get this error “UIKit/UIKit.h” file not found.
I’ve added this code in `.pro : LIBS += framework UIKit`.
Can someone tell me how can i use `UIImagePickerController` in qt?

Comment: I solved my problem.
when in desktop kit I type in #import <UIKit/UIKit.h> I get the error, "UIKit/UIKit.h" file not found.

I looked up this error and I found some answers that said UIKit is not included in MacOSX, but it is specific to iPhone: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1194897

good luck

Comment: I found the solution from this link: http://forums.bignerdranch.com/viewtopic.php?f=77&t=3431